# delete object from vector c++ attempting to reference deleted function

Tags: c++, object, vector

I've been looking around to see if anyone has a similar issue to me and i couldn't find anything. I am prompting the user to type in the name of the planet they wish to delete. My function will locate the position of the planet within the vector objects.

The purpose of this function is to delete a object based on the position i pass through the function parameters.

**Planet Class**

```
class Planet {
private:
    string name;
    double diameter;
    double mass;

public:
    const double G = 6.67408e-11;
    void setName(string n);
    bool setDiameter(double d);
    bool setMass(double m);
    string getName();
    double getDiameter();
    double getMass();
    double CalcSa();
    double CalcV();
    double CalcDensity();
    double CalcG();
    string InputS(string x);
    double InputD(string x);
    Planet();
};

double ReadDouble(double input) {
    //Verifys that that user entered in a correct number
    while (cin.fail() != 0) {
        cerr << "Enter a valid number: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(255, '\n');
        cin >> input;
    }
    return input;
}

string Planet::InputS(string x) {
    string user_input;
    cout << x;
    cin >> user_input;
    return user_input;
}

double Planet::InputD(string x) {
    double user_input;
    cout << x;
    cin >> user_input;
    user_input = ReadDouble(user_input);

    return user_input;
}


Planet::Planet() {
    name;
    diameter = 0.0;
    mass = 0.0;
}

void Planet::setName(string n) {
    name = n;
}

bool Planet::setDiameter(double d) {
    bool rv = false;
    if (d > 0.0) {
        rv = true;
        diameter = d;
    }
    return rv;
}

bool Planet::setMass(double m) {
    bool rv = false;
    if (m > 0.0) {
        rv = true;
        mass = m;
    }
    return rv;
}

string Planet::getName() {
    return name;
}

double Planet::getMass() {
    return mass;
}

double Planet::getDiameter() {
    return diameter;
}

double Planet::CalcSa() {
    double sa = 4.0 * M_PI * pow((diameter / 2.0), 2.0);
    return sa;
}

double Planet::CalcV() {
    double v = (4.0 / 3.0) * M_PI * pow((diameter / 2.0), 3.0);
    return v;
}

double Planet::CalcDensity() {
    double den = mass / CalcV();
    return den;
}

double Planet::CalcG() {
    double r = diameter / 2.0;
    double grav = (G * mass) / (pow(r, 2.0));
    return grav;
}
```

My issue is with this line of code:

```
l.erase(l.begin() + n);


void DeleteVector(vector<Planet>& l, int n) {
    if (int len = l.size() > 0) {
        cout << l[n].getName() << " was removed from the list.\n";
        l.erase(l.begin() + n);

    }
}
```

i pass in the vector of planets which is a class. and then i pass in the position "n" which i wish to remove from the vector of objects.

I get the following error:

```
Error   C2280    'Planet &Planet::operator =(const Planet &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Something about `class Planet`, not shown, makes it impossible to reassign objects, and `vector<Planet>` needs that to move its elements in memory when one is erased.

Comment: @aschepler I updated the post with my class planets

Comment: `const double G = 6.67408e-11;` `const`s can't be reassigned. If this `const` doesn't change between instances, consider making it `static const`.

Comment: I didn't add this to my answer, as it is not related to the question, but `if (int len = l.size() > 0)` probably neither does what you think it does, nor would doing what you think it does make any sense anyways. It will assign `1` to `len` if `l.size()` is greater than 0, otherwise it will assign `0` to `len`. It will then check if `len` is non-zero, and if so, enter the if-body. Basically it just checks if `l` is empty or not. You probably want `if (n < l.size())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy assignment operator for your class `Planet` is implicitly deleted by your compiler, because it has a `const` member.

See [Deleted implicitly-declared copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator):

> A defaulted copy assignment operator for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following is true:
>
> - T has a non-static data member of non-class type (or array thereof) that is const;

You probably meant `G` to be `static const`:

```
static const double G;
```

and then outside of your class:

```
const double Planet::G = 6.67408e-11;
```